# Schema Diff Timeout issue with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

When perform schema diff for 2 databases with Visual Studio Pro 2017, I'm facing with issue about schema diff timeout because the database in server too large, so the result always display no differences detected.

With Visual Studio 2015, I can workaround by increasing the "QueryTimeoutSeconds" in regedit and it's working as normally. But when upgrade to Visual Studio 2017, I can't find anywhere have this value

Have anyone experiance with this issue and have any solution workaround?

My environment:
- SQL Server 2017 Developer
- Visual Studio 2017 Pro
- SSDT 15.1.61710.120

Answer (score 2):

After more investigation, I found that in Visual Studio 2017, we can updating `QueryTimeoutSeconds` in regedit, but a little configuration because Visual Studio 2017 already hive the regedit.

First, please close all Visual Studio 2017 application, after that, open regedit application.

Choose `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, click `File` and choose `Load Hive`, and paste the link to address: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`, select `15.xxx` and choose `privateregistry.bin` -> Click `Open`.

Input `VS_2017_LoadHive` in the appeared dialog and click `OK`.

Expand `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >  VS_2017_LoadHive`, and find `QueryTimeoutSeconds` key under `SQLDB > Database`, after that increased the value to 6000.
After that, select `File` and choose `Unload Hive`.

Open Visual Studio 2017 again and enjoy.

Comment: I tried searching for this answer directly in Google, but it didn't show up.  Doing the search from stackoverflow and answer found.  Either way this worked great for me, so thanks for taking the time to post the answer.  Also couldn't find this answer on the Microsoft site.

Comment: This also works for Visual Studio 2019.  Just select 16.xxx instead of 15.xxx and use the VS_2019_LoadHive instead of VS_2017_LoadHive.