# Cannot modify MSBuild 15.0 private registry on build server

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools, regedit, sqlproj

We are experiencing this query timeout issue when trying to publish a SQL Server database project:
[Schema Diff Timeout issue with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681093/schema-diff-timeout-issue-with-visual-studio-2017)

I want to use the workaround on headless build machine, where Visual Studio IDE installation is not present, but build tools are available instead:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/microsoft-build-tools

There is no privateregistry.bin in folder %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx\, actually the 15.0 folder does not even exist on the server. How to extend the query timeout on this build server?

Comment: Can't you just upload the file from a machine that does have VS installed?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we are experiencing this error on our build & deployment server and this is not about building the database project but publishing the database. These pages tell about the same problem as the SO question I mentioned already in my question.

https://digitalsupport.ge.com/en_US/Article/DACPAC-deployment-issue-Unable-to-reconnect-to-database-Execution-Timeout-Expired
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/566bce33-c79b-444c-9db5-70556ad4a423/failed-to-import-target-model-dbname-detailed-message-unable-to-reconnect-to-database?forum=ssdt

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround: We must split sql database project builds and deployments. We need to produce a dacpac file in the first place and deploy the database with sqlpackage.exe included in SSDT. That executable has an explicit timeout parameter.